# Non-wrapping content inside a position: absolute container with variable width

Tags: css, css-float

I have some divs and buttons inside a div placed in a div with position: absolute, as in this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gahilo/ZDfRt/)

The code:

```
<div class="buttons">
    <div class="button-line">      
        <div>Edit</div>
        <div>Cancel</div>
        <input type="submit" class="wd-edit" value="Submit">
    </div>
</div>
```

Where:

```
.buttons {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 0;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 100%;
}
.button-line > * {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

See the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gahilo/ZDfRt/) for complete content.

My problem is that whether I use display: inline-block of float-left for the childrens of the div .button-line, the buttons inside wrap, and I don't want that.  I want the width of the .button-line div to adapt to the size of it's content, and all the buttons on the same line.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this the crux of what you need? [Fiddle me this](http://jsfiddle.net/SKJFK/)

Basically the meat of the operation is done with

```
white-space:nowrap;
```

I've taken off all of your styling so you can see what's going on more clearly.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding:

```
.button-line.b3 {
    white-space:nowrap;
}
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/ZDfRt/5/)**